# Showing and hiding views with transitions in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

i try to make 'showing and hiding views with transitions' in Animations (with swiftUI) ;

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var isShowingRed = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button("tap me") {
            withAnimation {
                isShowingRed.toggle()
            }
        }
        
        if isShowingRed {
            Rectangle()
            .fill(.red)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200) 
            transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .scale, removal: .opacity))
        }
     }
   }
  }

      struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
         }
     }
```

but got error like ;
An unknown crash has occurred, check back for more information. How to fix that erro,any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: You forgott the `.` in front of `transition(.asymmetric`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to put a `.` before `transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .scale, removal: .opacity))`.

That might be why.